# How can I round of a double type value up to two decimal places without changing it's data type from double in Java?

Tags: java, types

Suppose for example I have these values

```
Double d = 59 
Double d2 = 85.2658
```

Now I want this d to be printed as 59.00 and d2 as 85.26 and both should be of same double data type only.

Approach I tried to follow which is not working

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("####0.00");
System.out.println("Value: " + df.format(d));
```

This is converting it to String which is not correct it is working but giving output in String type "59.00" and "85.26".

When I am parsing it to double

```
Double parsed = Double.parseDouble(df.format(d));
```

It is printing 59.0

Can anyone suggest some alternative?

Comment: You can't because that is simply not how double works. You need to separate presentation concerns (formatting) from the actual double value.

Comment: a double is still a double no matter how you print it...

Comment: the easiest way for you to represent a number to 2d.p is by using BigDecimal i know you mentioned you don't want to change type from double but this is just not viable for double type as that is not how it works